# Excel: Searching within array for minimum dates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate the columns E and F automatically via Excel formula.  Shown below to illustrate the desired output. Column E is the minimum date in the table for that project whose row I am at.  And column F is the minimum date in the table for the project and status whose row I am at.  Thank you for the help.

[image]

Comment: Did you try `MINIFS`?

Comment: Thank you for the hint.  Yes that seems to have done it.  
=MINIFS($D$2:$D$14, $A$2:$A$14, A2)

Comment: A follow on question  - if the Timestamp column above is a string and I need to extract the date - say using LEFT function - how would I do that?  When I try =MINIFS(Left($D$2:$D$14,10), $A$2:$A$14, A2) excel doesn't like the formula.

Comment: You'd have to use `SUMPRODUCT`, an entirely different approach than `MINIFS`.

Comment: Got it. For now I'll do the "preprocessing" in another column and then use that new column as input to the MINIFS.  Would have been neat to do it in one shot, but not the end of the world.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As @BigBen pointed MINIFS solves the problem.  I posted the answer in comment above. I also found this article for reference: [Earliest and Latest Project Dates](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-earliest-and-latest-project-dates)